# Recommend Software for Drawing a Normalization Diagram

Tags: database, normalization, diagram, database-normalization, database-diagram

I want to draw database diagram. I should draw normalization steps.

I want to draw diagram like this and show functional dependency!

```
                           --------------------------
                           |            |           |
                           |            v           v
                     -------------------------------------
                     | user_name  | first_name | last_name|
                     --------------------------------------
```

Do you know any open source software to draw a diagram like this?

I use from DIA but Dia not support diagram like this

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ORM](http://www.orm.net/) is an excellent diagrammatic way to represent dependencies. I don't think there is any standard notation for exactly the type of diagram you are looking for but ORM will do the job nicely. You can even generate a normalized database design directly from an ORM model.

Answer (score 0):

I've used dia ([link](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/)). Which is Free Software and it is quite good.
And googling I've found this [one](http://www.edrawsoft.com/entity-relationship-diagrams.php).

Comment: How you can draw this diagramm with dia ?

Comment: I don't want to draw ERD Diagram

Comment: The question asks about how to draw dependency diagrams, not ERDs.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both Microsoft PowerPoint and Visio to draw them. Unfortunately, neither of these has any kind of automatic dependency diagram features (unlike ERDs). The solution is to draw boxes (rectangles) with names of attributes in them, and then draw arrows that show the dependences. It's slow and not so flexible, but it works for display-only purposes.

The same can also be done with the FOSS Dia (non-automatic); the following YouTube video shows how to do this with Dia: https://youtu.be/wFOJnRxqrp8.